Multipart objects from part of a text
The text is joined by nearest to the objects.

But is there a way to multipart objects just from text? E.G.'T1-I11', 'T1-I5'
As there are multiple objects with the first half of the text, is it possible to multipart from a certain part of the text.
The closest I got for this to work is by using the aggregate tool.

Aggregate should work.
Split the string into an array with string_to_array, slice the first two elements of the array, and convert back to a string:
array_to_string(array:=
array_slice(array:=string_to_array(string:="X", delimiter:='-'), start_pos:=0, end_pos:=1), delimiter:='-')


